# catch error in promise with settimeout

Tags: javascript, исключения, promise

Нужно отловить ошибку из промиса с сеттаймаутом и при этом получить id сеттаймаута что бы можно было его остановить.
Код с которым я это пытаюсь сделать

```js
const globalTimeout = async () => {
  let timeoutId; 
  const timeoutPromise = new Promise(() => {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      throw new Error('Request timed out');
    }, 4000);
  });
  return {
    timeoutPromise,
    timeoutId,
  };
};

async function loop() {
  const { timeoutPromise, timeoutId } = globalTimeout();
  await timeoutPromise.catch(err => { throw err;});
}

(async() => {
  try {
    await loop();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Промис выполняется только **один раз**, поэтому в таком виде это работать не будет. К тому же, локально объявленный в функции промис тут никак не используется. Поэтому, код нужно полностью переписывать в соответствии с другим (верным) алгоритмом. Опиши задачу, которую ты пытаешься решить (не алгоритм неверного решения как ты его представляешь, а именно **задачу**: не то что пытаешься выполнить - а что пытаешься создать, цель/назначение решения).

Comment: Если это попытка имитировать в JS выполнение в отдельном треде с таймаутом неудачи (выполнение какой-то асинхронной задачи в течение определенного времени но не дольше) - то надо добавить и код основной асинхронной задачи, т.к. без него теряется весь смысл. Например, если асинхронной задачей является запрос, то добавь запрос к httpbin.org

Comment: Цель такая - ест функция глобального таймаута которая находится в другой функции loop , и эта функция loop обернута в try catch и по идеи должно работать так: если вылезла ошибка из глобального таймаута, то try catch должна ее обработать

Comment: Вот эту функцию `loop` и надо добавить в пример вoпроса, т.к. без нее весь практический смысл кода примера теряется (участникам желательно понимать задачу вопроса, чтобы ее не приходилось угадывать).

Comment: Обновил код в вопросе

Comment: @Jhartum и що, за этим обязательно new Error тягать? Цель - обломать луп если он долгий?

Comment: @Vadim в целом да, new error как пример, это нужно потому что на его месте будет расширенный дефолтный класс ошибки JS`а

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ожидание выполнения какой-либо функции в течение отрезка времени возможно только если эта функция возвращает промис (за исключением случаев когда функция сама управляет прерыванием своего выполнения по внешнему значению) - потому что асинхронные очереди в цикле событий выполняются **после** синхронного кода итерации.

Естественно, и синхронный код функции промиса всегда выполняется полностью (если не добавлять в него выход по условию какого-то внешнего состояния). В общем, невозможно "снаружи" прервать уже выполняющийся код промиса: мы можем лишь выбирать, нужен ли нам его результат. Здесь выбор делается в зависимости от времени выполнения.

Проще говоря, принцип такой: мы помещаем в асинхронную очередь два промиса (один с полезным кодом; другой с отклонением по таймауту), и `try..catch` срабатывает по-разному в зависимости от того какой из этих промисов исполнится раньше. Пример ниже - показывает как можно объединить это в один промис:

```js
const globalTimeout = (callback, delay = 4e3) => {
  let timeoutId;
  const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error('Request timed out'));  // отклоняем, по таймауту, в этом случае `resolve` не имеет эффекта
    }, delay);
    const result = await callback();           // ожидаем выполнения асинхронного коллбэка...
    clearTimeout(timeoutId); 
    resolve(result);                           // ...и резолвим результат
  });
  return { promise, timeoutId };
};

function loop() {
  // какие-то действия... (код этой функции - имитация)
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const isLongExecution = Math.random() < 0.5;
    setTimeout(
      () => resolve('Hello Stack Overflow!'),
      isLongExecution ? 5e3 : 0
    );
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const { promise } = globalTimeout(loop);
    console.log(await promise);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err.message);
  }
})();
```

В примере сценарий выполнения `loop` выбирается случайным образом (иногда быстрое, а иногда долгое - во втором случае промис таймаута исполняется раньше).
Конечно же, при "внешней" отмене таймаута через `clearTimeout`, его промис останется незавершенным (навечно в состоянии *pending*).

*// Не вижу тут причин возвращать значение `timeoutId`, т.к. логичнее сразу снимать таймаут если коллбэк "успел"... но на всякий случай оставил это значение в возвращаемом объекте.*

Comment: Спасибо огромное, это похоже на то, чего я пытался добиться

Comment: @Jhartum, пожалуйста! Еще советую посмотреть на статический метод `Promise.race()` - реализация на нем обычно гораздо удобнее/нагляднее, но я не стал его использовать тут (чтобы решение было похоже на код вoпроса). Принцип тот же: запускаем те же два промиса (с полезным кодом и отклонением по таймауту), который успел раньше тот и молодец. Разве что с передачей id таймаута в `loop` будет облом при `Promise.race()`, т.к. этот id является локальной переменной. Ну, это думаю понятно/очевидно.

Answer (score -1):

Я обычно не использую `try{}catch(){}` в твоём кейсе, самостоятельно запрашивать еррор - ну такое

у setTimeout задаешь количество секундочек - отложенных на выполнение реквеста

С этим способом тебе не нужно будет получать ид таймаута и тд

```js
// true  = data from the request
// false = timeout "error"
const fast_fetch = false;

const fetch = async()=>{
    // fetch placeholder
    return await new Promise((done)=>setTimeout(()=>done('da'), fast_fetch ? 100 : 300));
};

const loopa = async()=>{
    return await new Promise((done)=>{
        let tookLong = true;

        fetch('url').then((r)=>{
            tookLong = false;
            done({ok: true, data: r});
        }).catch((e)=>{
            done({ok: false, data: e});
        });

        setTimeout(()=>{
            if(!tookLong)return false;
            done({ok: false, data: 'Request timed out'});
        }, 200);
    });
};

(async()=>{
    const response = await loopa();
    // if(!response?.ok)throw new Error(response.data);
    console.log('done', response);
})();
```